# How can i compare the date value of firebase with android system date

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am comparing the date of system with the date I have stored in firebase in the form of key-value pair. I have retrieved the date and time, but it's not working.

I already retrieved value from firebase using map. It retrieves the value of date and time and show in toast, but it is not comparing with the system date.

```
rootrefen.child("Timer").child("Setquiztime").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


        Date c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c);

        DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
        String date = df1.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        Map<String ,Object> hash_map=(Map<String,Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

        String getdate=hash_map.get("Date").toString();
        String gettime=hash_map.get("Time").toString();


        Toast.makeText(DateAndTimePicker.this, getdate+"--"+gettime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(DateAndTimePicker.this, formattedDate+"--"+date, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm aa");
        String getCurrentTime = sdf.format(c.getTime());
        String firebsetime=sdf.format(getdate);

        if (formattedDate.compareTo(getdate) < 0)
        {
            if(getCurrentTime.compareTo(firebsetime)<0)

            Toast.makeText(DateAndTimePicker.this, "Working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            btndiss.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(DateAndTimePicker.this, "Not Working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            btndiss.setEnabled(false);


        }



    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: `String getdate=hash_map.get("Date").toString();
            String gettime=hash_map.get("Time").toString();` You are toasting those two values so you know what they are. You forgot to tell us. You should tell all values of course. Put them as comments in your code please. If you added Log.d() statements you could better see what happens.

Comment: Have you solved the issue? Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: no i am just comparing Date and Time of firebase values with the system time i am getting no errors but it's not working also